# What is the default behavior of violating the Authorize attribute in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

What is the default behavior of violating the `Authorize` attribute in ASP.NET Core?

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public ActionResult ShutDown()
{

}
```

It seems that it redirects to the `/Account/AccessDenied` if the user doesn't have enough rights and `/Account/Login` if the user didn't login yet.

Am I right?

I don't see anything about it in the docs.

Comment: Found this -**The default MVC templates are configured to redirect HTTP 401 responses to a login page that will then return the logged-in user to the previously unauthorized page.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on which authentication middleware you're using.

The cookie based authentication  middleware will, by default, redirect an unauthenticated user to /Account/Login, and an already authenticated user to /Account/AccessDenied. This behaviour can be turned off by setting the AutomaticChallenge flag in the middleware options, as which point it will just return an HTTP 401 response when the user is not logged in, or 403 when the user is logged in, but doesn't fulfill the authorization requirements.

JWT bearer middleware will only return 401 or 403 status codes.

Other middlewares may behave differently, depending on what standard they are trying to implement.

Comment: How can I check which middleware my project actually uses?

Comment: You need to examine your startup.cs and figure it out from there.

Comment: I see `AddIdentity` there. That's it?

Comment: Yes. That uses cookies, and thus the cookie answer applies.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. Where did you find this info about `AddIdentity` being used `/Account/Login` and `/Account/AccessDenied`? Is it mentioned somewhere in the docs?

Comment: I know it, because, I review that code. It doesn't appear to be documented anywhere. Please file an issue in the aspnet docs repo. https://github.com/aspnet/Docs

Answer (score 2):

I thought it might be useful to follow the code and understand what is going on. The default [`AuthenticationHandler`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/918d6127457b88bbb45de5e7efd8ccf1e95d9d6a/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/AuthenticationHandler.cs#L319) will just return **401**(Unauthenticated) or **403**(Forbidden). After that, depending on your project configuration different authentication handlers will be added to the pipeline.

- For example, when you use [`AddIdentity`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L47) and [`UseIdentity`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/BuilderExtensions.cs#L39), you also call [`UseCookieAuthentication`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/22d2fe99c6fd9806b36025399a217a3a8b4e50f4/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAppBuilderExtensions.cs#L47) behind the scenes, which in turn adds the `CookieAuthenticationMiddleware`.
- The [`CookieAuthenticationMiddleware`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/22d2fe99c6fd9806b36025399a217a3a8b4e50f4/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationMiddleware.cs#L63) will replace the default handler with the [`CookieAuthenticationHandler`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L365), although by default the previous handler [will be kept](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/918d6127457b88bbb45de5e7efd8ccf1e95d9d6a/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/AuthenticationHandler.cs#L371) as the prior handler. That way handlers might decide not to participate and let the previous handler handle the result. (This is important to understand how the `AutomaticChallenge` flag works)
- The `CookieAuthenticationHandler` will redirect to the `AccessDeniedPath` or the `LoginPath` which are taken from the options. By [default](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationDefaults.cs) these paths are `/Account/Login` and `/Account/AccessDenied` but they can be [overriden](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/22d2fe99c6fd9806b36025399a217a3a8b4e50f4/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationMiddleware.cs#L49) by Identity when it [calls UseCookieAuthentication](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/BuilderExtensions.cs#L39). (Only LoginPath is [overriden](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IdentityCookieOptions.cs#L33) but the same value is used).
- You could manually update those paths as well, for example:

  ```
  services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(opts => 
        opts.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/my-login"));
  ```

The `AutomaticChallenge` flag mentioned by @blowdart is set as true by default when [Identity](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IdentityCookieOptions.cs#L32) adds the cookie authorization middleware. When you set that as false, the cookie handler will [not participate](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/918d6127457b88bbb45de5e7efd8ccf1e95d9d6a/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/AuthenticationHandler.cs#L338) and the prior handler will be executed, returning 401 or 403. (As the prior handler will be defaul the default one)

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(opts => 
                              opts.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge = false);
```

Comment: To be strict about it, cookie middleware, regardless of it being added by identity, or manually, will have AutomaticChallenge set. None of the other MSFT supplied middlewares set that. If nothing is set to automatic nothing will happen at all when you encounter an Authorize attribute.